# GRU as a Classifier

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, sequence-to-sequence, gru

Hello Data Scientists,

I have sensor data dataset consists of (10 features and labels), the labels classify the data to (normal or 4 type of attacks). The Label is encoded (0,1,2,3,4).  There is a sequence (pattern) between the rows.
**Dataset Structure:**

| ID | D0 | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | D6 | D7 | D8 | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |

Thus, I want to use GRU as a classifier  to classify the data to its label. The reason for choosing GRU as a classifier is to capture the data sequence or hidden pattern.

**My questions are:**

- Is it possible to use the GRU in this case? For labelled dataset?
- When I convert the input data (ID, D0….D8) to sequence and try different time steps, how can I deal with the labels? Convert them to sequence too?

Can you please advise me in this. I appreciate your help.